# Printing the root of the numbers from 4 to 9999

Tags: javascript, typescript, root

I want to print the root of all numbers to 9999. How do I tell the program to skip the numbers that don't have a round root? Here's the code

```
let i=1;

for (i===1;i>=1 && i <10000;i++){
    let b = Math.sqrt(i);
    console.log(`${i} = ${b}`);
}
```

Comment: btw: i wonder what's a reason to make the `i===1` check in the first part of your for-clause; is that a typescript thing? since this could be just omitted in regular js oO

Comment: In fact, `i===1` there is invalid in JS.

Comment: In both languages when you write only two ==
Example: 
Let a = 5;
Let b = "5";
if (a==b)....
It will consider it as true , because it turns a in a string of 5. When you have === , 5 won't be equal to "5", because the one is a number and the other is a string type.
Shortly === checks not only the value, bit the type too

Comment: ok to clarify, i didn't ask about the === but _why_ you would write a condition in the place where usually the initialization of the indexer takes place. because the value of the condition isn't used: in fact you could just write `false` instead of `i===1` and it still works.

Comment: Just 2 cents of mine. This is not an exact duplicate plus the OP is totally a newbie.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if both the `int` value and the original value are same.

```
let i=1;

for (i=1;i>=1 && i <10000;i++){
    let b = Math.sqrt(i);
    if (Math.trunc(b) == b)
        console.log(`${i} = ${b}`);
}
```

Instead of `Math.trunc(b)`, you can use either of the following:

- `Math.round(b)`
- `Math.floor(b)`
- `Math.ceil(b)`
- `parseInt(b, 10)`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Xcd: Don't iterate over all possible values of the number. Iterate over all possible "roots", instead.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate and test every number up to 10000. You can directly compute powers of two:

```
var count = 0, i = 0;
while (count < 10000) {
  i++;
  var b = i * i;
  console.log(`${i} = ${b}`);
  count = b;
}
```

Or as mentioned in comments you can do it elegantly with for-loop:

```
for (let i = 1; i*i < 10000; i++) {
  console.log(`${i*i} = ${i}`);
}
```

Comment: Shorter: `for (let i = 1; i * i < 10000; i++){ console.log(\`${i*i} = ${i}\`);}`

Comment: Also, your `while` condition isn't right. you're only getting up to `31`, while the last result should be `99`

Comment: I can't see the point in that code. I wan't to print the root of the numbers.

Comment: @Xcd: You want all possible values, for which the root of said value is a integer. So why not iterate over said integers? That's way faster than iterating over every possible value, taking the root of it, and checking if it's an integer.